# R 3.5.2: Pipe inside custom function - object 'column' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, chaining

I am having issues with pipes inside a custom function. Based on the previous posts, I understand that a pipe inside a function creates another level(?) which results in the error I'm getting (see below).

I'm hoping to write a summary function for a large data set with hundreds of numeric and categorical variables. I would like to have the option to use this on different data frames (with similar structure), always group by a certain factor variable and get summaries for multiple columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    count  mean
  <fct>      <int> <dbl>
1 setosa        50  5.01
2 versicolor    50  5.94
3 virginica     50  6.59
```

I'm hoping to create a function like this:

```
sum_cols <- function (df, col) { 
df %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(count = n(), 
mean = mean(col, na.rm = T)) 
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
sum_cols(iris, Sepal.Length)

Error in mean(col, na.rm = T) : object 'Petal.Width' not found
Called from: mean(col, na.rm = T)
```

I have had this problem for a while and even though I tried to get answers in a few previous posts, I haven't quite grasped why the problem occurs and how to get around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You might find this guide useful: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try searching for non-standard evaluation (NSE).

You can use here `{{}}` to let R know that `col` is the column name in `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

sum_cols <- function (df, col) { 
  df %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(count = n(), mean = mean({{col}}, na.rm = T)) 
  }

sum_cols(iris, Sepal.Length)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species    count  mean
#  <fct>      <int> <dbl>
#1 setosa        50  5.01
#2 versicolor    50  5.94
#3 virginica     50  6.59
```

If we do not have the latest `rlang` we can use the old method of `enquo` and `!!`

```
sum_cols <- function (df, col) { 
   df %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(!!enquo(col), na.rm = T)) 
}

sum_cols(iris, Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: @Karina Do you have `rlang` 0.4.0 or higher installed? Load the library with `library(rlang)` and then try this.

Comment: I have 0.3.1 - I have a work computer, and installing and updating packages is not up to me, sadly. I tried it on my personal computer, and it worked fine so it does seem to be an issue with the older versions.

Comment: Ok...updated the answer which should work similarly.